# Printing Float Values to Console

Tags: python

I am using python to print the RPi CPU temperature to the console. The below method (function), returns a float which converts Celsius to Fahrenheit `get_cpu_temp()`. However the float value is incorrect. I am assuming my print command is incorrect, not the calculated float value. For example:

Prints:

```
CPU Temp: 84772.40 F 
CPU Temp: 46.54 C
```

Code:

```
print("CPU Temp: %.2f F"  % get_cpu_temp())
print("CPU Temp: %.2f C"  % get_cpu_temp_c())

def get_cpu_temp():
    tempFile = open( "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp" )
    cpu_temp = tempFile.read()
    tempFile.close()
    return float(1.8 * float(cpu_temp))+32

def get_cpu_temp_c():
    tempFile = open( "/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp" )
    cpu_temp = tempFile.read()
    tempFile.close()
    return float(cpu_temp)/1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your °F code, you forgot to divide by 1000. So this line:

```
return float(1.8 * float(cpu_temp))+32
```

should read

```
return float(1.8 * float(cpu_temp/1000))+32
```

To avoid coding errors like this, calculate the °C value, and investigate using [Quantities](https://pythonhosted.org/quantities/) to do the units conversion.